# What Debian OS for HP proliant server

Tags: linux, debian

This is my server:

http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/15351-15351-4237916-4237918-4237917-4248009.html?dnr=1

I want to install a command line (no GUI) version of the latest stable debian. I am confused though about which version of Debian to put on, for example, is there a "debain server" which is debian without the GUI? Also I can see that it uses an AMD processor but I cant see if it is 64 bit of 32 bit.

Comment: Just adding a little bit to the answer above: Usually for a server connected to a network you can install only the "[netinst](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/6.0.6/amd64/iso-cd/)" install, a [basic installation](http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst#smallcd) that you can add the packages that you gonna need later. Otherwise just use the first CD in the link that you provided. If the machine is not connected to the Internet at all you can try downloading first the 3 CDs and installing what you need. The packages in the CDs are ordered by popularity of the packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian is debian - there is no seperate server and desktop variant, and the difference is entirely in package selection. If you have a stable connection, debian minimal is a good starting point, else download the first cd of the install set. You can choose to install what you want as you go along.

The [Turion II Neo](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Turion%20II%20Neo%20N40L%20-%20TEN40LGAV23GME.html) on those systems is certainly 64 bit capable, and so you can run either. There's not much reason *not* to run 64 bit, especially if you max out the ram on the system.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean I want this:
http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/6.0.6/amd64/iso-dvd/

Comment: Furthermore, there seems to be 8 files there. Am I really meant to burn them onto 8 seperate disks?

Comment: go with disk 1 *only* - or even the two smaller versions - business card or netinst. [The ISO CD versions](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/6.0.6/amd64/iso-cd/) would be sufficient and contains all 3 - Pick one. The other disks are for folk who want to download *everything* due to say, unsuitable internet connections at the install site.